# Using Log4j2, the JPA or JNDI appender dosen't work in a JPA exception

Tags: java, jpa, logging, log4j, log4j2

i'm using log4j2 in my project with maven, jpa and EJB...

my log4j2.xml are configurated to register on database logs from error and fatal levels.

however,
when has an exception in the JPA, the JPA or JNDI appender dosen't work!
But, when other exception occurs, the log4j2 logs in my database.

### Example:

**DOSEN'T WORK:**

```
try{
   Query query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("mynamedquery");
   stackEntity = query.getResultList();
}catch( Exception ex ){
   logger.catching(ex);
   logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
   logger.fatal(ex.getMessage(), ex);
   throw new MyPersistenceException(Errors.E2002);
}
```

**IT'S WORK:**
But works if i change the "getResultList" by throws exceptions, like:

```
//listaPerfilEntity = query.getResultList();
throw new Exception("foobar");
OR
throw new RuntimeException("fuuuu");
```

somebody knows why?

Thks

Comment: Your query might not throw any exception when it runs thats why it doesn't log exception. You can just debug your code to check where it goes

Comment: the:
`stackEntity = query.getResultList();`

throw an exception, because table or view does not exist...
i'm validating the logs on data base, but this dosen't log

Comment: have you run your code in debug code ? is it coming in catch block ?

Comment: they are,
the code works fine, 
but when i rename the table used by "getResultList" instruction, to test... The debbuging go to catch block, but the logger dosent log in the database.

Comment: Please also show your full log4j2.xml configuration file.